# Load specific page instead of redirect, in case of 404 error in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, divi

Normally whenever a 404 error occurs, the 404.php file or page specified in the template is displayed.

for example

page : product | page_id = 20

```
function custom_404(){
    if (is_404()) {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->is_404 = false;
        status_header(200);
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

        $wp_query = new WP_Query(['page_id' => 20]);
        
        get_header();
        
        //method1
        the_content();
        
        //method2
        echo do_shortcode( ' [my_shortcode] ' );
        
        
        get_footer();
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_404');
```

**But the problem:**
My WordPress theme is [divi](https://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/). The template is not fully loaded.
Headers and footers load without js, css codes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own 404 script you should try using the built in functionality whenever possible.

The easiest way to set up a 404 page using the Divi theme is to go to **Divi > Theme Builder** in your admin menu.

[image: Theme Builder Menu Location]

Then click **Add New Template**, scroll all the way to the bottom and select **404 Page**

[image: Template Menu]

Then click **Add Custom Body** and you can edit it just like any other page. The Global Header and Global Footer won't show up while you're editing because you're only working on the Custom Body of the page.

Make sure to save your changes in the editor before closing it. Then you'll also need to click **Save Changes** at the top of the Theme Builder page to save the theme.

Now any url that doesn't resolve to an existing page or post should be redirected to this template.

Here's the full tutorial from the makers of Divi: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/how-to-create-a-404-page-template-with-divis-theme-builder